# add class to button after select - jquery

Tags: jquery, addclass

I have a submit button which is disabled until a user chooses from a select list.

I want to remove the disabled attribute and also add a class so the button becomes the standard button class I use throughout the site, on change of the select list.

I am trying the following:

```
$(document).ready(
function(){
    $('#category').change(
        function(){
            if ($(this).val()) {
                $('input:submit').attr('disabled',false);
                $('#btn_show').addClass.attr('button green');

            }
        });

});
```

#category is the drop-down id and #btn_show is the button id

The disabled is removed ok but the class not added. Is my logic correct?

Also, is it also possible to change the value of the submit button when this change happens too?

Comment: can you post a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Also, addclass should be something like $('#id').addClass('class to be added')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `$('#btn_show').addClass('green');`

Please read the manual: http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Comment: then the classses should be separated by a space

Comment: Short, simple and helpful answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

this can be done by jquery [`addClass('class_name')`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) api

try this

```
$('#btn_show').addClass('button green');
```